# TypeError at / 'NoneType' object is not iterable Request Method: GET Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Tags: python, django

When I run my Django application I get this error

```
TypeError at /
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

In my views.py this is what I have

```
def user_login_request(request):
    print('calling user_login_request')
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('calling user_login_request POST')
        #  a form bound to the POST data
        login_form = TGArchiveUserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            # print('calling login_form.is_valid()')
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get("user_login_name")
            password = login_form.cleaned_data.get("user_login_password")
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                # print("You have logged in as " + request.user.username)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}.")
                return redirect(reverse('members:dashboard'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    context = {
        'user_login_form': TGArchiveUserLoginForm()
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="auth/tg_login.html", context=context)
```

I have changed the template name and send a blank context to the template and still get the same error code.

This is the traceback I got when I run the application

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/members/views.py", line 32, in user_login_request
    return render(request=request, template_name="auth/tg_login.html", context=context)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 168, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/projects/tg/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 244, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
[07/Oct/2021 14:04:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 91879
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. I have added the traceback.

Comment: Please post the version from the console.

Comment: @KlausD. I have added the traceback from the console.

Comment: This looks like one of your context processors returned `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Change request type. You are sending get request but in your view you have POST method. Your context is also not iterable. Share full traceback, so that exact error can be detected.

Comment: I have shared full traceback

Comment: I have my own custom HTML form so do I need to send this in my context?

        context = {
            'user_login_form': form
        }

Comment: I just found out that I cannot even render a blank HTML page. still getting the NoneType error

Comment: Yes. Django can find forms at HTML side only if we pass them in context @user3689322